# Interaction between viewmodel and view

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I working with windows phone apps and using MVVM and in my viewmodel I get loading data code in there that the property of the loaded data is bind into my view(XAML) so how can I get information about data being load and loaded? because I need to add ProgressIndicator in my xaml so my user can know there is loading for the data...

if I'm not using mvvm and put all my code into mainpage.xaml.cs then I just need to put ProgressIndicator  directly into my loading code like this

> SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = true;
>
> SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = true;
>
> (..my logic code..)
>
> SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = false
>
> SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = false;

if it in mvvm then how I to do that?

Comment: *then I just need to put ProgressIndicator directly into my loading code like this* That wouldn't work, btw, unless ***(..my logic code..)*** runs on a different thread...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally interaction between ViewModel and View in MVVM pattern happen through data-binding, and in some special case through messages using Messanger pattern. This case can be accommodated in the general scenario, using data-binding. Create property in your viewmodel to indicate a brackground work in progress, `IsBusy` for example. Bind ProgressIndicator `IsIndeterminate` and `IsVisible` property to `IsBusy` :

```
<shell:SystemTray.ProgressIndicator>
    <shell:ProgressIndicator IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsBusy}" 
                             IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" 
                             Text="{Binding Message}" />
</shell:SystemTray.ProgressIndicator>
```

With data-binding, your code structure in viewmodel can be simply as follow :

```
IsBusy = true;

await MyFunction();

IsBusy = true;

....
private async void MyFunction()
{
    (..my logic code..)
}
```

Check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19557878/2998271) for further reference.