# Progress bar that is visible on all pages in my app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, progress-bar

For example in one page of my app I am downloading several images asynchronously. I want to keep visible the progress bar to notify the download status of the images. But when I leave current page the progress bar disappears. Is there any way to show the progress bar in all pages?

Comment: Have you considered displaying download progress in the [System Tray](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19557878/815938)?

Answer (score 0):

if you navigate from one page to other the Objects get disposed that's why you are not able to see progress bar on navigation.

Solution to this is to use default windows phone progress bar using below method. Try to include this method in your base class which extend **Page** class.

```
  public static void ShowLoader(string loaderMessage, bool showProgress)
    {

        StatusBarProgressIndicator progressbar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ProgressIndicator;

        progressbar.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(loaderMessage) ? "Please wait..." : loaderMessage;

        if (showProgress)
        {

            progressbar.ShowAsync();

        }

        else
        {

            progressbar.HideAsync();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Think that would only work for WP8.1 runtime.  Not sure.

Comment: Thanks @heena for updating my code. This will work in both 8 and 8.1.

Comment: @Somdev Singh, will you please explain the following line: "**StatusBarProgressIndicator progressbar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ProgressIndicator;**"

Comment: @raisul - This will initialize the current views progress indicator which will be available further for showing your text and progress indicator.

Comment: Looks like I do not have **StatusBarProgressIndicator** class and **StatusBar** is also not recognized by IDE. Am I missing something? @Somdev Singh